# Keras, How to define padding in Convolution2D?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

In the [Convolution2D docs of keras](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/), I found there are no details on definition of `padding`

```
keras.layers.convolutional.Convolution2D(nb_filter, 
                                         nb_row, 
                                         nb_col, 
                                         init='glorot_uniform', 
                                         activation=None, 
                                         weights=None, 
                                         border_mode='valid', 
                                         subsample=(1, 1), 
                                         dim_ordering='default', 
                                         W_regularizer=None, 
                                         b_regularizer=None, 
                                         activity_regularizer=None, 
                                         W_constraint=None, 
                                         b_constraint=None, 
                                         bias=True)
```

the `subsample` argument is

> tuple of length 2. Factor by which to subsample output. Also called strides elsewhere.

and I think it is stride.

And the `border_mode` argument  is

> 'valid', 'same' or 'full'. ('full' requires the Theano backend.)

`valid` and `same` are also arguments in TensorFlow's conv2d function.

How to define the padding, how to set the value of it?

Answer (score 5):

What you want is the [ZeroPadding2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding2d) layer, just put it before a convolutional layer. This is more flexible than just putting this functionality inside Convolution2D.

Comment: Thx, if there is no ZeroPadding2D defined in the code, does it mean that the default padding is 1 in `Convolution2D`, the output size `W'=(W-F+2*P)/S + 1`

Comment: @AlexanderYau Default padding depends on the border mode.

Comment: @Matias: And the kernel size.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer above mentioned the ZeroPadding2D layer in Keras. However, if you want to use some other kinds of padding which are not provided by Keras, such as reflection padding, you should implement them by yourself.

As far as I know, there are two ways to custom padding layer in Keras:
1. Use [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer in Keras, and call the [padding](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/pad) function from Keras's backend(typically TensorFlow).
2. Define your own Layer class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677544/reflection-padding-conv2d) for more details.