# Reflection padding Conv2D

Tags: python, keras, padding, conv-neural-network, zero-padding

I'm using keras to build a convolutional neural network for image segmentation and I want to use "reflection padding" instead of padding "same" but I cannot find a way to to do it in keras.

```
inputs = Input((num_channels, img_rows, img_cols))
conv1=Conv2D(32,3,padding='same',kernel_initializer='he_uniform',data_format='channels_first')(inputs)
```

Is there a way to implement a reflection layer and insert it in a keras model ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution! We have only to create a new class that takes a layer as input and use tensorflow predefined function to do it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras.engine import InputSpec

class ReflectionPadding2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, padding=(1, 1), **kwargs):
        self.padding = tuple(padding)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=4)]
        super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_output_shape_for(self, s):
        """ If you are using "channels_last" configuration"""
        return (s[0], s[1] + 2 * self.padding[0], s[2] + 2 * self.padding[1], s[3])

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        w_pad,h_pad = self.padding
        return tf.pad(x, [[0,0], [h_pad,h_pad], [w_pad,w_pad], [0,0] ], 'REFLECT')

# a little Demo
inputs = Input((img_rows, img_cols, num_channels))
padded_inputs= ReflectionPadding2D(padding=(1,1))(inputs)
conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='valid', kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
               data_format='channels_last')(padded_inputs)
```

Comment: But shouldn't the padding come before the convolution in the demo?

Comment: That did now work for me. still had the same shape afterwards

Comment: @ChristofHenkel check out my answer below. You should change the function name get_output_shape_for to compute_output_shape.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer above is not working in the current Keras version. Here is the version that's working:

```
class ReflectionPadding2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, padding=(1, 1), **kwargs):
        self.padding = tuple(padding)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=4)]
        super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, s):
        """ If you are using "channels_last" configuration"""
        return (s[0], s[1] + 2 * self.padding[0], s[2] + 2 * self.padding[1], s[3])

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        w_pad,h_pad = self.padding
        return tf.pad(x, [[0,0], [h_pad,h_pad], [w_pad,w_pad], [0,0] ], 'REFLECT')
```

Comment: jeevaa_v, can you explain a but about what you wrote? even a reference article which explains what reflection layers do, would be great

Comment: I have just created a custom layer in Keras using tensorflow's reflection padding. Regarding reflection padding or other kind of padding, see here: www-cs.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/cs470/hw/hw2_pad.txt

Comment: This implementation is helpful and clean, thanks for sharing!

Comment: There is a big problem here if you use padding larger than (1,1) and save your model. when you load it, it will try to do (1,1) padding because it is initialized that way in the __init__ and the model will fail to load. I can't figure a way around it so I'd use the Lambda solution below if you have this problem.

Comment: https://www.machinecurve.com/index.php/2020/02/10/using-constant-padding-reflection-padding-and-replication-padding-with-keras/#reflection-padding

Answer (score 2):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Lambda

inp_padded = Lambda(lambda x: tf.pad(x, [[0,0], [27,27], [27,27], [0,0]], 'REFLECT'))(inp)
```

The solution from Akihiko did not work with the new keras version, so I came up with my own. The snippet pads a batch of 202x202x3 images to 256x256x3

Comment: really simple and effective solution

Answer (score 0):

As you can check in the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d) there is no such 'reflect' padding. Only 'same' and 'valid' are implemented in keras.

You maybe try to implemented on your own or find if somebody already did it. You should base yourself in the `Conv2D` class and check where `self.padding` member variable is used.

Comment: I know that this is not yet implemented in keras. But, how to implement a reflect layer and add it to a keras model ?

Comment: Then you should clarify your question, to say that you want to implement padding by reflection.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work if we have undefined dimensions! There will be an error when compute_output_shape function is called. Here is the simple work around to that.

```
class ReflectionPadding2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, padding=(1, 1), **kwargs):
        self.padding = tuple(padding)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=4)]
        super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, s):
        if s[1] == None:
            return (None, None, None, s[3])
        return (s[0], s[1] + 2 * self.padding[0], s[2] + 2 * self.padding[1], s[3])

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        w_pad, h_pad = self.padding
        return tf.pad(x, [[0, 0], [h_pad, h_pad], [w_pad, w_pad], [0, 0]], 'REFLECT')

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(ReflectionPadding2D, self).get_config()
        print(config)
        return config
```